# Are AWS Error Codes available from the Java SDK?

Tags: aws-java-sdk

One of our production customers just had a problem uploading a file to S3. When the error was printed out to the log, we received a undescriptive error message:

```
com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.AmazonS3Exception: BadRequest(Service: AmazonS3;StatusCode: 400;ErrorCode:400BadRequest;RequestID: XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX)
```

400 Bad Request maps to a large number of errors:

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/ErrorResponses.html

It is impossible to debug on this error alone. My question is, how can I get an Error Code (as listed in the html page above) from the Java SDK when an error happens? Is there a generic way getting descriptive Error Code not just for S3, but for all AWS Java SDK Errors?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to get access to the full XML response that S3 sends back to the Java SDK using [getErrorResponseXml](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/s3/model/AmazonS3Exception.html#getErrorResponseXml--) on `AmazonS3Exception`.

Comment: Is there anything specifically though that just returns the error code or will we need to parse the XML?

Comment: @RobertAllurent did you ever resolve how to get the error code?